# Export a sql database table to a text file using vc++

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-c++, export

I am trying to export a SQL database table to a text file. I can create the file but its blank. I think the issue is with the Fill() but I'm not sure. Any help would be great.

```
SqlCommand^ myCommand = gcnew SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [CSC 289].dbo.Inventory ;", myCon);
          SqlDataReader^ myReader;
          StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter("File.txt");

          SqlDataAdapter^da = gcnew SqlDataAdapter();
          da -> SelectCommand = myCommand;
          DataTable^ dt = gcnew DataTable();

          for each(DataRow^ row in dt -> Rows)
          {
              for each(DataColumn^ col in dt -> Columns)
              {
                  da -> Fill(dt); 
                  sw -> WriteLine(dt);
              }
          }

          sw -> Close();
          delete sw;
```

Comment: Where are you executing the command?

Comment: I am not sure. Where would I add one?

Comment: Call your fill outside the loop with the datatable and then iterate the rows.

Comment: I moved the fill outside the loop but the file is still empty. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to get the value from the row using the column name. Something like row[col.ColumnName].ToString(), not sure about the c++ syntax.

Comment: Fixed it thank for you help. the correct syntax is:

sw -> Write(row[col->ColumnName]->ToString());